# "User's expertise" or "user expertise"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, possessives, determiners, modifiers

What is the correct form when referring to the expertise of a user (e.g. in programming, writing)?

> 1. user's expertise
> 2. user expertise

Comment: Either version sounds pretty odd to me in relation to *programming* or *writing*. "Users" are usually distinguished from "software writers" who have "expertise" at programming. And I don't understand what it would mean to say you have "user['s] expertise" in writing. An author who's "good at reading" other people's books?

Comment: Programmers are often at the same time users of some kinds of programming environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the expertise of a particular user, then it would be *the user's expertise,* but if you mean the general concept of expertise developed by users, then *user expertise* would be clearer. For the general concept, you could, however, also say *users' expertise,* or perhaps *users' collective expertise.*