# "user's details" or "user details"

Tags: possessives

user's details or user details, which one is the correct form when referring to the details of a user in a database?

Regards

Comment: related: [User’s/Users’/Users Group](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/user-s-users-users-group?lq=1)

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56262/users-expertise-or-user-expertise?rq=1) post answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't be simpler --  because "user details" is now the accepted standard.